# Command line for using perl script on multiple files

Tags: perl, command-line, command-prompt, fastq

The perl script given to me contains:

```
use strict;

open(IN1, "<".$ARGV[0]);
open(IN2, "<".$ARGV[1]);
open(OUT, ">".$ARGV[2]);
```

at the start and is supposed to be run on multiple fastq files. I'm not sure what command line to use so that the perl script goes through the multiple files in the folder.

One of the lines i tried is:

```
perl script.pl *.fastq.gz
```

Comment: If you want to read gzip compressed files, look into [`IO::Uncompress::Gunzip`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html). (And Bioperl, to avoid having to try to write your own fastq format reader)

Comment: What does the script do? Any guesses based on its name or docs/comments? Does it really accept compressed files (\*.fastq.gz) or only uncompressed files (\*.fastq)?

Answer (score 2):

This program is expecting to be called like this:

```
$ program.pl input1.dat input2.dat output.dat
```

So you currently need to to give it two input files and an output file.

If you want to change it to process more than two input files, then you'll (presumably) still need to pass it an output file as well. Something like this, perhaps:

```
$ program.pl *.fastq.gz output.dat
```

And then inside your code, you can write:

```
my $outfile = pop @ARGV;
my @infiles = @ARGV;
```

You would also have to change the code that opens filehandles as it's currently hard-coded to use two input files and an output file.

But, here's something else to consider. Perhaps, don't open any files at all. Instead, write your code as a Unix-style filter.

```
$ program.pl input_files* > output.dat
```

Then simply read from `<>` (the empty file input operator) and write to `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the three lines of code in the question, you should give it exactly three parameters:

```
script.pl [input file 1] [input file 2] [output file]
```

Using a wildcard as you attempted to do is unlikely to work properly (unless the correct three files are in the directory *and* sort into the correct order in the directory listing).

Worse, there's a possibility that it may have damaged the third file matching `*.fastq.gz`, as the script may have attempted to write output into it unless the script has sufficient error checking to have noticed that it got the wrong number of arguments and abort - and, given that there are no error checks in the three `open` statements you posted, it seems unlikely that it would make such a check.

Answer (score 0):

A typical usage to run the script like this would be

```
perl script.pl in.1.fastq in.2.fastq out_file
# or:
perl script.pl in.1.fastq.gz in.2.fastq.gz out_file
```

Often, the two input files are read 1 and read 2 fastq files, the results of paired end sequencing runs, for example on Illumina sequencers.

Using `*` in this context could be problematic, as it may expand into more that 2 files (not what you want).

To run for more than one pair of fastq files, do something like this. Make a file with 1 sample name per line, for example file `samples.txt` such as this (I am assuming no blanks in sample names):

```
sample_a
sample_b
...
```

Then run the script on each sample, for read 1 and read 2:

```
cat samples.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} perl script.pl {}.1.fastq {}.2.fastq {}.out
```

Here,
`xargs -n1` : executes the command for each 1 string (here, for each line),
`-I{}` : assigns the word to `{}`, which we then reuse for the file names.